# Реализация многоуровневых категорий Laravel

Tags: php8, laravel-10

Есть следующая таблица в бд:
[image: таблица категорий]

Соответственно вот миграция для нее:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Сделал модель и связь следующим образом:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function childrenCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
}
```

И контроллер:

```
public function __invoke()
{
    $categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')
        ->with('childrenCategories')
        ->get();
    return view('categories', compact('categories'));
}
```

Что ж, и отображаю вот так:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        <li>{{ $category->name }}</li>
        <ul>
            @foreach($category->childCategory as $childCategory)
                @include('child_category', ['child_category' => $childCategory->name])
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
```

Хочу получить фидбек, является ли такой способ "нормальным", а также нужно помочь решить ошибку: когда перехожу на другую вложенность второй форич берет и нулабельные поля, поэтому выбрасывает такую ошибку foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
Очень жду ответа, заранее спасибо!